# Error when building spinnaker echo

Tags: echo, spinnaker

[Snapshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e2AJ.png)

```html
2018-05-21 19:34:43.570  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Initializing system.IndexInfo
2018-05-21 19:34:43.574  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Initializing system.local
2018-05-21 19:34:43.577  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Initializing system.schema_triggers
2018-05-21 19:34:43.581  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Initializing system.schema_columns
2018-05-21 19:34:43.584  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Initializing system.batchlog
2018-05-21 19:34:43.587  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Initializing system.peer_events
2018-05-21 19:34:43.590  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Initializing system.paxos
2018-05-21 19:34:43.602  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Initializing system.compactions_in_progress
2018-05-21 19:34:43.604  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Initializing system.range_xfers
2018-05-21 19:34:43.607  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Initializing system.schema_keyspaces
2018-05-21 19:34:44.337  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.a.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor  : Couldn't detect any schema definitions in local storage.
2018-05-21 19:34:44.340  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.a.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor  : To create keyspaces and column families, see 'help create' in cqlsh.
2018-05-21 19:34:44.575  INFO 24007 --- [           main] o.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore  : Enqueuing flush of Memtable-local@8933868(148/1480 serialized/live bytes, 5 ops)
2018-05-21 19:34:44.586  INFO 24007 --- [  FlushWriter:1] org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable         : Writing Memtable-local@8933868(148/1480 serialized/live bytes, 5 ops)
2018-05-21 19:34:44.673 ERROR 24007 --- [  FlushWriter:1] o.a.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon    : Exception in thread Thread[FlushWriter:1,5,main]

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.Iterators.emptyIterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator; from class org.apache.cassandra.db.DeletionInfo
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DeletionInfo.rangeIterator(DeletionInfo.java:255) ~[cassandra-all-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex$Builder.build(ColumnIndex.java:122) ~[cassandra-all-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.rawAppend(SSTableWriter.java:211) ~[cassandra-all-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.append(SSTableWriter.java:196) ~[cassandra-all-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:392) ~[cassandra-all-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runMayThrow(Memtable.java:345) ~[cassandra-all-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[cassandra-all-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

Try to run echo in local as instruction on the https://github.com/spinnaker/echo with command ./gradlew bootRun.
And i see the error as the pic.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please expand on your question. As written, it is unclear what you are asking, what you have tried or what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i am sorry first time to use stackoverflow.

Comment: Not a problem! :)
Take a look at this - should help for future reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the embedded cassandra failed to start. Try adding `spinnaker.cassandra.enabled = false` to your config or as a env variable. ( i,e. SPINNAKER_CASSANDRA_ENABLED=false ./gradlew bootRun)